# Disabling SET Statements / Forcing SET Options in SQL Server 2008R2/2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, configuration

I am currently working with a SQL Server 2008 R2 database which uses the following `SET` commands frequently:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS { ON | OFF }
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER { ON | OFF }
SET ANSI_PADDING { ON | OFF }
```

While I was researching these settings I stumbled across the following note for `ANSI_NULLS` on Microsoft Technet ([Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)):

> In a future version of Microsoft SQL Server ANSI_PADDING will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will produce an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Because of this I would like to enforce a "global" setting. I have been searching for the better part of a day but as I understand it you can always change these settings. To be completely sure I would like to ask here:

Is it possible to either enforce a setting like `ANSI_NULLS ON` or to disable the possibility of changing these settings on "any" level?

I would like to use this to test if the database would "survive" if the ability to set a specific option to OFF is disabled.

I hope I was able to describe my problem. This is not my first language.

Thanks in advance.